# git push не работает на heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Перестала работать синхронизация с репозиторием на Heroku.

git pull работает

git push выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

День назад все работало. В чем проблема?

Comment: А что изменилось со вчерашнего дня?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы.
Ситуация решилась сама собой.
Очевидно, что проблема была на стороне Heroku.
Вопрос закрыт.